# How do I disable an app's display scaling for notch compatibility?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a 2021 M1 Pro MacBook Pro with a notch at the top of the screen. The OS is macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

I've seen that there is a setting for scaling down the screen for compatibility with apps that don't account for the notch, but I don't know where this setting is. When I open TeamViewer and fullscreen the window with the remote computer's display in it, macOS automatically scales it for notch compatibility, meaning that the screen shrinks on the top, left, and right. However, the remote computer's display is 16:9 so it wouldn't go behind the notch anyway.

I would like to disable this compatibility shrinking such that I get to use the full width of my display for TeamViewer (or likewise for any other app). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The setting is called "Scale to fit below built-in camera", which is a checkbox in the app's info panel:

1. Open **Finder** and go to **Applications**
2. Find **TeamViewer**, Right-Click or Ctrl-Click it, and choose **Get Info**
3. Uncheck **Scale to fit below built-in camera**

[image: The macOS Finder "Get info" pane for TeamViewer. The "Scale to fit below built-in camera" box is highlighted and unchecked.]

Worth knowing that, if you do happen to find an app that has compatibility problems with the notch, this checkbox is available for all non-built-in apps, so you can check it to use this scaled mode!

Comment: I have quite a few games (right now it's Endless Space 2 that's bothering me) which seem to scale to fit below the notch regardless of which way this option is toggled - even if they are set to a native 16:10 resolution like 3456x2160 or 1728x1080 which should fit perfectly below the notch anyway. Is there any way to force it to stay disabled for fullscreen apps?

Comment: The problem is that if this checkbox is unchecked, it's automatic. If the checkbox is checked, it's forced scaled. There is no way to force unscaled.

Comment: @AaronFranke did you find any workaround for this? I just got a new 15" Air and 50% of the reason I did this was because I thought "well with the new extra 1/3 extra inch in the screen It'll be almost like my 2019 16 inch", until I discovered Apple's latest nightmare... a software-defined forced Bezel.

Comment: @AaronFranke I found this: https://notes.alinpanaitiu.com/Fullscreen%20apps%20above%20the%20MacBook%20notch